# Is it possible to have two coordinated verbs before 得/不 + resultative?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to have two coordinated verbs before 得/不 + resultative?

Something like:

他改和写不下去

他吃和喝不下

他擦和洗不干净

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential particle 得/不 work with one verb at a time, all your examples are ungrammatical

Correct examples

他[改写]不下去 --one verb

他[擦洗]不干净 -- one verb

他[吃]不下饭, [喝]不下水 -- two verbs, two sets of potential particle

More examples:

他听和看得到雷声和闪电 (X)

他听得到雷声, 看得到闪电 (O)

Comment: I guess this happens when you think in English and write in Chinese?

Comment: Something like:- "I ate the hamburger and a bag of chips and still feel hungry?"